# create one single object when using per session contract

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to make a wcf service with a per session contract. but I want that all the instances for every session will have **one single object** that all the per session instances have an acsess to it.

If I wasn't clear, I want to create a seperate service instances for each client, but that all of them have access for one separete common memory.

I can use static variable in the service class to achieve this, but isn't there another way structred in the wcf?

Comment: Erm... use a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.Runtime.Caching classes to achieve this.  The default memory cache is scoped to the process level, so it should do what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may create your own Service Host Factory, that would somehow (e.g. like Jason suggested in Memory Cash) store your reference to your "single object" service, and would create new service hosts with reference to your "single object"

Answer (score 0):

No WCF does not provide an [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) mid-way between PerSession and Single.

To achieve the behavior you require you can use a static class or [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).